# iterate / compose function onto itself n times

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

Supposed I have an arbitrary function

```
foo = function(a,b) {a+b}
```

How can I iterate this function onto itself `n` times?

`foo(foo(foo(foo(x, 1), 2), 3, 4)`

I am looking at `purrr:compose` but it doesn't look hopeful for arbitrary `n`. `purrr:reduce` feels like it will come into play also... but I'm stumped.

Comment: probably something closer to:  `do.call(compose, as.list(rep('foo', n)))`

Comment: `ff <- function(x) Reduce(foo,c(x,1:4))` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure `purrr` version, that is really functional, as you said `reduce` comes in handy here, since `compose` is just a function and functions are just elements you can reduce functions by composing them. To just fill one argument use `partial`.

```
foo_n <- reduce(map(1:n, ~partial(foo, b=.x)), compose)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just append results of each `foo(a,b)` function into a numeric vector and then pick up the last result.

Let's `x = 1` and `b`s are elements of `1:4`:

```
x = 1
n = 4

out = vector("numeric")
steps = seq(1, 4, by = 1)

for( b in steps){
  ## initial value
  if (length(out) == 0){

      out = append(out, values = foo(x, b) )
    }else{

      out = append(out, values = foo( tail( out, 1), b) )
    }

}
tail(out, 1)
```